# Regex: Match all the spaces and all parenthesis from a string

Tags: regex

I am trying to select all spaces, tabs and parenthesis from a `String` with `regex` but I am not sure if it's possible with a single statement and I can't seem to find a valid answer.

```
\s+          //Matches any whitespace character.

\\(|\\)+     //Matches any parenthesis
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You might want to use `[\s()]+`, but *all* parentheses might mean you also want to include half-width and full-width parentheses, and other weird stuff like `｠`

Comment: That works like a charm! How can I validate your answer? Even for weird stuff as you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [**character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
[\s()]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zRWGkj/1).

Here,

- `[` - start of a character class that matches...

  - `\s` - a whitepsace
  - `(` - left parenthesis
  - `)` - right parenthesis
- `]` - end of the character class
- `+` - 1+ repetitions.

To include the Unicode symbols that are similar to parentheses, add `\u0028\u0029\u1ABB-\u1ABE\u207D\u207E\u208D\u208E\u23DC\u23DD\u27EE\u27EF\u2985\u2986\u2E28\u2E29\uFD3E\uFD3F\uFE35\uFE36\uFE59\uFE5A\uFF08\uFF09\uFF5F\uFF60` to the regex (iPCRE, you need to replace `\u` with `\x` and wrap the code with `{...}`):

```
[\s()\u1ABB-\u1ABE\u207D\u207E\u208D\u208E\u23DC\u23DD\u27EE\u27EF\u2985\u2986\u2E28\u2E29\uFD3E\uFD3F\uFE35\uFE36\uFE59\uFE5A\uFF08\uFF09\uFF5F\uFF60]+
```

It will also match

```
᪻  ‎1ABB  COMBINING PARENTHESES ABOVE
᪾  ‎1ABE  COMBINING PARENTHESES OVERLAY
⁽  ‎207D  SUPERSCRIPT LEFT PARENTHESIS
⁾  ‎207E  SUPERSCRIPT RIGHT PARENTHESIS
₍  ‎208D  SUBSCRIPT LEFT PARENTHESIS
₎  ‎208E  SUBSCRIPT RIGHT PARENTHESIS
⏜  ‎23DC  TOP PARENTHESIS
⏝  ‎23DD  BOTTOM PARENTHESIS
⟮  ‎27EE  MATHEMATICAL LEFT FLATTENED PARENTHESIS
⟯  ‎27EF  MATHEMATICAL RIGHT FLATTENED PARENTHESIS
⦅  ‎2985  LEFT WHITE PARENTHESIS
⦆  ‎2986  RIGHT WHITE PARENTHESIS
⸨  ‎2E28  LEFT DOUBLE PARENTHESIS
⸩  ‎2E29  RIGHT DOUBLE PARENTHESIS
﴾  ‎FD3E  ORNATE LEFT PARENTHESIS
﴿  ‎FD3F  ORNATE RIGHT PARENTHESIS
︵  ‎FE35  PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT PARENTHESIS
︶  ‎FE36  PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT PARENTHESIS
﹙  ‎FE59  SMALL LEFT PARENTHESIS
﹚  ‎FE5A  SMALL RIGHT PARENTHESIS
（  ‎FF08  FULLWIDTH LEFT PARENTHESIS
）  ‎FF09  FULLWIDTH RIGHT PARENTHESIS
｟  ‎FF5F  FULLWIDTH LEFT WHITE PARENTHESIS
｠  ‎FF60  FULLWIDTH RIGHT WHITE PARENTHESIS
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zRWGkj/3).

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down, I am still quite new to Regex and there's a lot to catch up on.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you want?
it will return you all succession of space, tab, ( ) that appear in your text in any order. 
    ((*)*\s*)*